# Batch file that copies file and rename to IP address in the name

Tags: ip, batch-file, file-transfer, rename, filenames

I'm not too familiar with batch files. Most commonly I use VBA/PHP, but I would like to have this one a go :).

I would like to:

**Fetch the user's IP address,
Copy a file,
and rename that file to ipadres.extension**

So the new file name should be the IP.

for example:

```
ipconfig | find "IPv4"
copy /y Expeditool.accdb Expeditool"IPv4".accdb
```

I tried, but just puts IPv4 in file name.

Could anyone help me out with this one?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A dirty example to get your IP:

```
for /f "tokens=14" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| findstr IPv4') do set _IPaddr=%%a
echo IP is: %_IPaddr%
```

You then use `%_IPaddr%` in your `copy /y Expeditool.accdb Expeditool"IPv4".accdb`

E.g.

```
for /f "tokens=14" %%a in ('ipconfig ^| findstr IPv4') do set _IPaddr=%%a
copy /y Expeditool.accdb Expeditool%_IPaddr%.accdb
```